# Moving a folder to a NAS mount

Tags: linux, centos, symlink

I currently have a small Centos VPS which has some local SSD disk - I am getting close to my storage limit as I am storing a lot of flat files which are accessed very infrequently so I am looking at getting some NAS disk and moving the files to it as it is much cheaper than getting more SSD and will still perform just as well.

The challenge is I don't want to have to update all my application references to point to a new location - is there any way I can have the current folder (lets call it /home/user/public_html/folder) pointing to a new location (for example /mnt/new_folder) without having to update anything so /folder/file.doc, ../folder/file.doc or www.example.com/folder/file.doc etc will still point to the files in question?

Will a symlink allow me to do that?

Answer (score 2):

A symlink will allow you to do that but if this is for Apache, you may get an error in some security contexts and need to enable the FollowSymLink directive.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

Alternatively, you can just mount the new NAS device directly your desired locations and add it to fstab.

Another solution I use is to create a /nas directory and then mount each nas device under this directory, e.g.

```
/nas/id1
/nas/id2
...
/nas/idX
```

The id numbers match that on my NAS appliance so I can easily keep track of them.

You can then use symlinks to link up these NAS devices to make them available in your public web space.

If using PHP, open_basedir and safe_mode may need to be changed as well.

Comment: An alternative to symlinks would be the Linux specific bind mount, allowing you to remount part of the file hierarchy somewhere else, effectively making the same contents available accessible in two places. `mount --bind olddir newdir`

Comment: +1 for "Just make the current folder into the mount point". Move the data, mount the NAS where the folder used to be. No worries about symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

You do know that *nix allows you to mount (remote) filesystems at any location, don't you?

I.e. mount your remote filesystem on a temporary location, stop your application, move your existing files to that remote filesystem, unmount and mount again at /home/user/public_html/folder and restart your application.